# How do I stop MSSQL truncating text when accessed from php?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I try to retrieve the contents of a Text field from mssql in php I only get back part of the contents.  I think its about the first 4000 characters.

How do I stop this.

Comment: Please post a small snippet of code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question

Find this section of your php.ini file and change to the values below.

```
; Valid range 0 - 2147483647. Default = 4096. 
mssql.textlimit = 2147483647 

; Valid range 0 - 2147483647. Default = 4096. 
mssql.textsize = 2147483647
```